# Retrieve only txt files from directory and sub directory

Tags: java

I am trying write java code to retrieve only .txt files, the code which I have written retrieves all files from a directory and its subdirectories. How do I add logic to retrieve only .txt files?

```
public List<File> getFiles(String path){
    File folder = new File(path);
    List<File> resultFiles = new ArrayList<File>();

    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for(File file: listOfFiles){
        if(file.isFile()){
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }else if(file.isDirectory()){
            resultFiles.addAll(getFiles(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        }
    }

    return resultFiles; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if(file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".txt")) {
    // use the file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or alternatively the Java 7 way

```
public List<File> getFiles(String path){
    PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:.txt");
    List<File> resultFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(path))) {
        for (Path pathEntry : directoryStream) {
            if (matcher.matches(pathEntry)) {
                resultFiles.add(pathEntry.toFile());
            }    
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resultFiles;
}
```

EDIT: Just noticed the subdirectories requirement, sticking to the Java 7 approach this solution address subdirectories as well.

```
public List<File> getFiles(String path){
    final PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:.txt");
    final List<File> resultFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
    try {
        Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get(path), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                if (matcher.matches(file)) {
                    resultFiles.add(file.toFile());
                }
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE; 
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resultFiles;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `isTextFile(file)` in the same `if` condition as `file.isFile()`

```
public boolean isTextFile(File file) {

    String fileName = file.getName();

    String extension = "txt";

    return fileName.endsWith(extension);
}
```

And instead of printing the `absoluteFileName` you can just add it to  `resultFiles`.

**EDIT**

You could also use [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/), and use their `FileUtils` class, which is extremely helpful for working with files.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the file path ends with .txt.

```
public List<File> getFiles(String path){
    File folder = new File(path);
    List<File> resultFiles = new ArrayList<File>();

    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for(File file: listOfFiles){
        if(file.isFile() && file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith( ".txt")){
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }else if(file.isDirectory()){
            resultFiles.addAll(getFiles(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        }
    }

    return resultFiles;

}
```